# Check if a specific script is present from an helper/extension method in MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, helpermethods

Is there a way to check in a helper/extension method if a certain script is present in a view?

My idea is to create a custom TextBoxFor() method where the focus is moved to the next input once the present one reach the maxLenght.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use javascript for this task?

Example:
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/02/javascript-automatically-move-cursor-to.html

Comment: It's an idea, but my helper method does other things. I thing it is handy to know if it is possible to access scripts from an helper method.

Answer (score 1):

You have JQuery AutoTab Plugin - http://autotab.mathachew.com/

Download the AutoTab Min JS - https://github.com/Mathachew/jquery-autotab/blob/master/js/jquery.autotab.min.js

Lets say I have a model -

```
public class Details
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

now create a view -

```
@model YourNameSpave.Details

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetData";
}

<h2>GetData</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Details</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "alphanumeric", maxlength = 10})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email,  new { @class = "alphanumeric", maxlength = 10})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.autotab.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.alphanumeric').autotab();
    });
</script>
```

And now you will get autotab functionality as you wished.

[image]